# How entity framework reveals properties and types of a code first entity in runtime?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I just want to know how Entity Framework internally works to reveal properties and their types in runtime, particularly in case of Code-First approach, where there won't be system generated code. Can some body give some heads up? I don't think System.Reflection was being used implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Code first was first presented to developers as part of the EF Feature
>   CTP1 in June 2009 with the name “code only.” The basic premise behind
>   this variation of using the EF was that developers simply want to
>   define their domain classes and not bother with a physical model.
>   However, the EF runtime depends on that model’s XML to coerce queries
>   against the model into database queries and then the query results
>   from the database back into objects that are described by the model.
>   Without that metadata, the EF can’t do its job. But the metadata does
>   not need to be in a physical file. The EF reads those XML files once
>   during the application process, creates strongly typed metadata
>   objects based on that XML, and then does all of that interaction with
>   the in-memory XML.
>
> Code first creates in-memory metadata objects, too. But instead of
>   creating it by reading XML files, it infers the metadata from the
>   domain classes (see Figure 1). It uses convention to do this and then
>   provides a means by which you can add additional configurations to
>   further refine the model.

[image: Code First Builds the Entity Data Model Metadata at Run Time]

> ModelBuilder will now take this additional information into account as
>   it’s creating the in-memory model and working out the database schema.

[By Julie Lerman](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232765.aspx)